# Unable to create table in Amazon redshift using Psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to make a simple script in python, which will fetch data from an endpoint convert it into a dataframe and write it to an Amazon redshift cluster and then automate the script using a cronjob from aws. I am using psycopg2 for connecting to the redshift cluster and the script executes the commands pretty well (creates table in redshift and writes the data as well). But when I try to see the table from a sql client the table doesnt show up

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
import psycopg2
mm_get = requests.get('endpoint link'})
mm_json=mm_get.json()
data_1 = json_normalize(data         = mm_json['data'],
                       record_path   = ['courses','modules'],
                       record_prefix = 'courses.modules.',
                       meta          = [['courses', 'id'], 
                                        ['courses', 'title'],
                                        'activated', 
                                        'createdAt', 
                                        'email', 
                                        'employeeId', 
                                        'firstName', 
                                        'group', 
                                        'id', 
                                        'lastName', 
                                        'phone', 
                                        'teams'
                                       ]
                       )
data_2 = json_normalize(data         = mm_json['data'],
                       record_path   = 'lessons',
                       record_prefix = 'lessons.',
                       meta          = 'id',
                       meta_prefix   = 'user.'
                       )
data_3 = data_1.merge(
    data_2,
    how = 'outer', 
    left_on = ['courses.modules.id', 'id'],
    right_on = ['lessons.moduleId', 'user.id']
)

cols = data_3.columns
cols = cols.tolist()
cols = pd.DataFrame(cols)
re_cols = pd.DataFrame(cols.loc[:,0].str.replace('.','_').tolist(),index=cols.index)
data_3.teams = data_3.teams.astype(str)
data_3.teams = data_3.teams.str.replace('[','')
data_3.teams = data_3.teams.str.replace(']','')
data_3.teams = data_3.teams.str.replace("'","")

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname='name',
                     host='hostname',
                     port='xxxx',user='username',password='password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('create table testing_learn.test (courses_modules_completionDate DATE, courses_modules_id int,  courses_modules_status TEXT,courses_modules_title TEXT, courses_id int,courses_title TEXT, activated bool, createdAt TIMESTAMP, email TEXT, employeeId TEXT, firstName TEXT, group_name TEXT, id TEXT, lastname TEXT, phone int8, teams TEXT, lessons_courseId int, lessons_date DATE, lessons_id int, lessons_lessonNumber int, lessons_moduleId int,lessons_score TEXT, lessons_title TEXT,user_id int);')
cur.close()
data_mat = data_3.as_matrix()
str_mat = b','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',x) for x in tuple(map(tuple,data_mat)))
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into testing_learn.test VALUES '+str_mat.decode('utf-8'))
```

I am able to see the data when I query the same table from python using psycopg2, but the same table doesnt show up. It would be of great help if anyone could help with what I am doing wrong here. Thank in advance.

Comment: The only thing possible is, you may be using incorrect `usernam/schema/url` while connecting with `sql client` OR you may not be `commiting` transaction after `insert` sql.

Comment: you are able to see the data via python but same table doesn't shows up? Please clear up where you are able to see and where not.

Comment: @NitinSingh yes I am able to see in python but not in the database

Comment: @RedBoy how do I commit transaction after insert sql? Any suggestions?

Comment: `conn.commit()` to commit the transaction, similarly, `conn.begin()` to begin transaction,

Answer (score 2):

According to Psycopg2-2.7.5 [official documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), the main entry points of Psycopg2 includes:

> - The class connection encapsulates a database session. It allows to:
>
>   - create new cursor instances using the cursor() method to execute database commands and queries,
>   - terminate transactions using the methods commit() or rollback().

Therefore, you need to call `con.commit()` every time after you call `cur.execute()` to make the changes to the database persistent. Otherwise your table won't show up in the database.